# How to route url paths with a dot to index.php with the PHP built-in server?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am serving a site locally with:

`php -S localhost:4444`

The url's generated are like: `linen-blazer-580.html`

So we get the error `The requested resource /linen-blazer-580.html was not found on this server.`

Normally on apache the `.htaccess` with `mod_rewrite` would route that request to `index.php` but because it has a `dot` in it, it is trying to find the file which does not exist.

Comment: what are your current rules?

Comment: I have found the solutions: https://www.sonassi.com/blog/magento-kb/running-magento-in-php-5-4s-built-in-web-server